# WPF Datagrid header binding for custom columns not getting working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I am trying to create custom columns with a label and a combobox for the column headers.
The first time the grid is loaded properly. On the click of the button, I change the itmesources of the Datagrid. I see the cells of the datagrid getting updated, but not the headers. I also see that the Datagrid_Loaded is not being called. On debugging I found that for "**Binding**" object I supply the **binding path**, but for **header** I supply the **source**, hence the header don't get updated. How to supply path for the header so that its is similar to that of **Binding**?

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
    if (grid.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
   StageVM data = grid.Items[0] as StageVM;
    if (data == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    int index = 0;
    foreach (StageItemVM param in data.Stage)
    {
        var binding = new Binding(string.Format("Stage[{0}].StageItem.Value", index));
        grid.Columns.Add(new CustomBoundColumn()
        {
            CanUserSort = false,
            HeaderTemplateSelector = this.FindResource("ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector") as  DataTemplateSelector,
            HeaderStyle = this.FindResource("StageHeaderStyle") as Style,
            Header = (new Binding().Source = param.StageItem.Key),
            Binding = binding,
            TemplateSelectorName = "StageRangeColumnTemplateSelector"
        });
        index++;
    }
}
```

And the customBoundColumn class is as follows:

```
 public class CustomBoundColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
     public string TemplateSelectorName { get; set; }
     protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
         var binding = new Binding(((Binding)Binding).Path.Path);
         binding.Source = dataItem;
         var content = new ContentControl();
         content.ContentTemplateSelector =(DataTemplateSelector)cell.FindResource(TemplateSelectorName);
        content.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
       return content;
    }
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
   {
       return GenerateElement(cell, dataItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this can help you:
[WPF DataGridTextColumn header binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237044/wpf-datagridtextcolumn-header-binding)

I had the same problem about binding datagrid headers with my ViewModel. It's a xaml based solution.

Comment: first time binding works properly for me. but as soon as I change the itemssource the problem is created. [link]:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853326/c-sharp-header-in-the-grid-not-getting-refreshed-updated) this says the exact problem